# Cannot enable TrueColor support in tmux via overriding terminfo

Tags: vim, tmux, xterm

dist: Arch Linux.

I have an st build from AUR and tmux from official repo.
In st I meet a good TrueColor support that works with last Vim version via termguicolors option.
But when i tried to bring this to tmux i faced some issues.

At first time the output of

```
tmux info | grep Tc
```

from inside of tmux was

```
197: Tc: [missing]
```

after reading tmux man page i found that this option must bring to tmux Tc

```
set-option -g terminal-overrides "st-256color:Tc"
```

where from my terminal emulator it returns me:

```
TERM=st-256color
```

But the result of tmux info still was the same.
Just for check i installed xterm and tried the same manipulation with it but it didn't give me another result.
After all tmux recognizes that terminal support 256 colors and emulates true color via it

Comment: just linking to a solution which work for me in case anyone is interested. Apparently it's even documented: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5416d0/true_colors_in_vim_under_tmux/d7z3d2u?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x. I, renamed `screen` to `st` since my terminal name is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify your copy of the terminal description to provide this flag:

```
infocmp -x >foo
edit foo, adding "Tc," after the end of any line ending with a comma
tic -x foo
```

That would work for ncurses (which is what you have with any Linux distribution), and [perhaps](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-netbsd.html#terminfo) NetBSD curses.

Comment: Thanks it works. But I stil don't understand if this flag is not standard why is it used to check that feature supported?

Comment: tmux and vim both use nonstandard features of the terminal description, requiring users to make odd changes...

Comment: Is there any good and comprehensive documentation of this? And I thought ANSI codes were strange…

Comment: Not really: the feature you're interested in came from some creative interpretation of a little-known ISO standard.  The standard as written doesn't exactly say what the feature does - we get only interpretation...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-a` to append to, rather than override the existing terminal capabilities:

```
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",*256*:Tc"
```

This will work for any terminal which advertises 256 colours.

Check that you don't have another `set -g terminal-overrides` somewhere later in your config file, too.

---

For `vim`, you'll probably also want:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```