# vim colorscheme completely wrong inside screen or tmux sessions

Tags: ubuntu, vim, tmux

I've been trying for 3 days now to get my colorscheme to display properly inside of a screen session versus at the terminal prompt outside of screen or tmux session.  I've read all the links and tried everything anyone suggested with zero success.  I've attached a few images below.  The first is what my vim session looks like outside of tmux or screen and the second 2 are inside of tmux and screen.  One with screen-256 color set and the other with xterm-256color.  They are different but neither are anywhere close to the gruvbox scheme I'm using.

I'm using an Ubuntu server 16 and have even tried to upgrade vim and screen programs to latest versions and doesn't change anything.

Anyone know how to get the color schemes to match?

Thanks,

[image: vim before running screen or tmux]

[image: vim inside screen with screen-color256]

[image: vim inside screen with xterm-256color]

[image]

This last picture is of running through tmux instead of screen.  I have that grayish background behind all the text and the rest of the background is black.  Very close to what I'm looking for but not sure why text background and rest of background aren't the same.

Comment: What tmux version? Did you enable RGB colour by putting Tc or RGB in terminal-overrides? Did you try setting TERM=tmux-256color inside tmux?

Comment: Related questions include https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319934/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348771/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29907/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118806/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118892/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/201779/5132 .

Comment: So I have been using screen and the answer is yes to all of that.  However, I'm currently setting up tmux to try it.  It is almost ok with colors except I'm not getting the proper background color.  I do have it set in the .vimrc file  as bg=dark but I get the last image I attached to post above.

Comment: version 2.1 of tmux

Comment: Also, if I set term to your suggested tmux-256color I get no colors at all.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, for anyone interested:

I ended up finding another post on internet stating to add

```
set t_ut=
```

in the .vimrc file.  Doing this clears the background color and fixed my issue.  So screen still does not work but tmux seems to be working properly with this latest entry.  Not sure what is going on but just needed to get things working and seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

t_ut turns off BCE. tmux should support BCE but it depends on the tmux version, I think 2.1 is too old.

Comment: BCE was implemented October 2016; 2.1 is a year older.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349040/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252078/5132