# How to import tmux setting for vim to normal vim?

Tags: bash, vim, tmux, vi, vimrc

When using tmux  my color/font/syntax highliting in VIM gets improved. How can i import that
red/yellow/white combination of color in .vimrc file. I want that.

VIM ON TMUX:
[image: Tmux]

AND THIS IS MY NORMAL UGLY VIM.
[image: ugly vim]

Weirdly, when i opened in tmux again, my normal vim color is now changed , yello in `-A` argument is gone
[image: gone]

Comment: The colors are brighter in first vim and red/yellow/white color are present.

Comment: IF you see carefully you will get the font is also improved in first one

Comment: A more legible question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348771/5132 .  Related questions include https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319934/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348771/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29907/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118806/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118892/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/201779/5132 .

Answer (score -2):

So, i found that term inside and outside tmux are different. Thus, when i did `export TERM=screen` i got beautiful vim instead of ugly one.

Comment: If you're not using screen or tmux, then setting this value is wrong and will break programs using your terminal.

Comment: Anyways for the time i use vim i use export TERM=screen other time i use export TERM=xterm256-colors